# how to displaying data one by one with loading in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have 100 data in database
and i will show this data on div but this data is show one by one
because if displayed simultaneously will feel lagg

this my ajax to take and show the data

```
$.ajax({ type: "POST", url: site_url, data: {
        limit: limit,
        get_produk: mobile_form
    }, dataType: "json", timeout: 60000, success: function(data) {
       var data_produk = data.produk;
       var list_produk = '';
         for (var i = 0, len = data_produk.length; i < len; i++) {
                      list_produk += '<div class="wrapproduk goto_detil addproduk_'+data_produk[i].id+'">';
                        list_produk += filter;
                            list_produk += '<div class="wraptopproduk" '+addonclick+'>';
                                list_produk += '<div class="imgproduk" style="background-image:url('+global_url+''+data_produk[i].image+');"></div>';
                                list_produk += '<div class="titleproduk">'+data_produk[i].trim_title+'</div>';
                                list_produk += '<div class="priceproduk">'+format_angka(data_produk[i].harga)+'</div>';
                            list_produk += '</div>';
                            list_produk += '<div class="produk_pay_button '+add_grey+' produk_limit_'+data_produk[i].id+'" id="produk_limit_'+data_produk[i].id+'">';
                                list_produk += '<div class="btn_addtocart btn_ripple prod_front" id="add_front" '+addcart+'>'+lang.btn_details+'</div>';
                                list_produk += '<div class="addmin">';
                                    list_produk += '<button class="btn_addtocart btn_ripple prod_minus prod_inline" id="prod_minus" onClick="btn_minus_cartfront(\''+data_produk[i].id+'\')"><img src="img/minus.png" width="20"></button>';
                                    list_produk += '<input type="text" value="0" id="val_prod_'+data_produk[i].id+'" class="prod_inline val_prod_'+data_produk[i].id+' ">';
                                    list_produk += '<button class="btn_addtocart btn_ripple prod_plus prod_inline" id="prod_plus" onClick="btn_plus_cartfront(\''+data_produk[i].id+'\')"><img src="img/plus.png" width="20"></button>';
                                list_produk += '</div>';
                            list_produk += '</div>';
                                list_produk += '<input type="hidden" value=\''+ JSON.stringify(data_produk[i]) +'\' id="dataproduk_'+data_produk[i].id+'">';
                        list_produk += '</div>';


           $('#content_newproduk').html(list_produk);
        }
   }
});
```

how to show data one by one to #content_newproduk with animation and loading

Answer (score 1):

You will have to get the data from server one-by-one. In your code above, you need to modify `url: site_url` so that it will return you one record at a time, let's say based on ID you are passing. Then you have to call the method in a loop.

But, since these calls would be asynchronous and independent, you may face issues in sequence on UI. So you need to consider following points:
1. Does sequence matters to you?
2. You need to keep track of requests sent e.g requestCount and then increase and decrease it appropriately.
3. Maintain the state of your loader based on the request count.

**Note:** Based on the situation you have mentioned, I think it would be better to get the data in batches rather than one by one. Based on performance or your requirement, get the data in batches (refer server side pagination) and then display them.